# .returning() is not supported by sqlite3 and will not have any effect

Tags: node.js, electron, knex.js, electron-builder, node-sqlite3

Recently, I noticed the yellow warning in my console saying,

> .returning() is not supported by sqlite3 and will not have any effect.

I'm using the `sqlite3` module with `knex.js`. It didn't put any effect on output but knowing what is it worths a lot. Here are my environment details.

**knex** v0.19.1
**sqlite3** v4.0.9
**Node** v10.16.9
**electron-builder** v21.2.0
**electron** v6.0.2

Comment: [Here you go some info](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1660)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a call to `.returning(...)` in somewhere in your app. Since you are using sqlite3 dialect that call is just ignored and will not have any effect on returned data.

For example:

```
await knex('table1').insert({ foo: 'bar' }).returning('*');
```

and

```
await knex('table1').insert({ foo: 'bar' });
```

will return exactly same thing on sqlite dialect.

Comment: And if there is no .returning in the app? Can it be an issue of knex & sqlite?

Comment: No it is no an issue at all. It is just a feature of Postgre SQL and oracle and some other databases that doesn't exist in sqlite / mysql.

Comment: Is there any possibilty to supress this message?!

Comment: There are few ways to get rid of it. You could decide to not use .returning() with sqlite  or by extending knex with a new .silentReturning() method which first checks used driver before deciding if .returning() should be called or by overriding logger functions in configuration and recognize/ignore that warning.

Answer (score 2):

The RETURNING syntax has been supported by SQLite since version 3.35.0 (2021-03-12). https://sqlite.org/lang_returning.html

Comment: Nice we need to add version switch for sqlite to knkex config to start supporting it.

Comment: i've just tried it on the latest version "sqlite3": "^5.0.2", "knex": "^0.95.11", still getting the warning and errors out